# How to remove event listeners while destroying CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a ckeditor plugin like this:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('testplugin', {
        init: function (editor) {
               editor.on('contentDom', function (e) {                
                    var body = editor.document.getBody();           
                    body.on('mouseup', function (e) {
                       alert('run!!!!');
                     });
                  });
        });
});
```

It work perfect in CKEDITOR version 3 (iframe base)

But when i upgrade to CKEDITOR version 4 (lastest - contenteditable base),

all event fire multiple times when i destroy then re-init ckeditor.

(using `CKEDITOR.instants.testEditor.destroy()` and `CKEDITOR.replace('testEditor',options);`)

i use: `removeAllListeners( )` to remove all event listeners to body but no change.

How can i complete destroy CKEDITOR 4 + All event listeners on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you use an inline instance, so `editor.document` is `CKEDITOR.document`. It means that every single instance shares the same `var body = editor.document.getBody();`.

To avoid duplicated events as a leftover of attached by "dead editors", you should either listen on [`editor#destroy`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-destroy) and call [`event#removeListener`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.event-method-removeListener) on every single one, or use [`editable#attachListener`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-attachListener) which automates that job for you ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/3hQBp/)):

```
editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {                                
    var body = editor.document.getBody();

    // This listener will be deactivated once editor dies.
    editor.editable().attachListener( body, 'mouseup', function() {
        console.log( 'run!!!!' );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: perfect! `editor.editable()` save my life :) thanks.

Comment: Thank you @oleq, your example helped me a lot. I had an error "Cannot read property 'checkFeature' of undefined" after I had destroyed my CKEditor if I had event listener. Method removeAllListeners didn't help.